# Files replaced with Finder on Mac creating a copy on Samba's .recycle

Tags: filesystems, osx, samba

## Scenario:

Ad Agency with Samba Server and multiple Mac users, 0 Windows users.

```
vfs objects = recycle
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:repository = /storage/files/.recycle/%U
```

## Workflow:

Before start working with some PSD file (or whatever they use) they copy it locally to not overload our network.

After finishing it they upload it again on the server.

## Problem:

Once the designer paste the file on the server using Finder, two things happens:

1. The original file is moved into .recycle
2. The file is overwritten

## Expected:

Only step two should happen, no file should be moved to recycle (this is taking lots of space).

So far, I've readed on [samba man page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/vfs_recycle.8.html) that by setting `vfs objects = recycle`, that it will intercept all deleting requests and move the file to recycle.

Is it expected that Finder (or any other file manager) raise an delete call everytime someone tries to overwrite a file?

Answer (score 0):

## Dirty Solution

I created another share entry like

```
[Recycle]
path = /storage/files/.recycle/%U/
# This entry has no recycle enabled
```

So they can actually clean they own recycle and free space on disk.

This is not what I really needed, but is a valid solution.